# Dynamically Added Div's dont take events in IE?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, dynamic

I have added few dynamic divs using javascript in my code.

```
$('div#Tips').append(''
    + ' <div class="singleTip" id="'+data.x+''+data.y+'">'
    + data.content
    + ' </div>'
);
```

I am showing this div when user hovers over some elements. However it doesn't work in IE. It works on all other browsers.
Can anyone please help ? I am new to this.

EDIT:  Added JS code

```
$('.tipPointer').hover(
    function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('div#allTips').children('div.singleTip#'+id).show();
    },
    function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('div#allTips').children('div.singleTip#'+id).hide();
    }
);
```

Comment: Where's your JavaScript code that implements the hover effects? Hit F12. Click the Script Debugger tab. Enable Debugging. What, if anything, do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem for IE and later on narrowed down to IE10 only.

To solve try adding background image to the div elements that are not displaying. For some reason it works even if a non-existing image is inserted, so I used one like following.

```
<?php   if (preg_match('~MSIE|Internet Explorer~i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {?>
<style type="text/css">
    .qtip{
        background-image:url(/none);
    }
</style>
<?php   }   ?>
```

I have also added a PHP check to implement this CSS only for IE , because other browsers will throw 404 error (and continue to load) for background image.

I don't remember where I got this solution from. If I find original link, I'll update the answer.